# Cordova Media plugin error 'Cannot use audio file from resourse' when recording to non-existing file

Tags: cordova, audio

When i install the app, and trying to record new audio, i get error "**Cannot use audio file from resource ...**" , because this file is not exist yet. After first record completed, file will be created, and error is gone, but it`s strange - to get error "file not exist", when you just trying to record this file. Anyway to handle this?

```
myMedia = new Media('documents://some_rec.wav', function() {}, ...);
myMedia.startRecord();
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm using cordova-plugin-media 2.3.0 "Media". You've any luck getting around this issue?